# Is it possible to Manipulate data "in-place" when passing data to a Component attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, blazor

Is there any way to manipulate data when assigning a value to a Component attriute? Somethig like this:

```
 <StatsCard Value=@_incomeExpensesSummaryData.PeriodExpenses.ToString("0.00\u20AC") Description="Expenses" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Layers" IconColor="Color.Secondary"></StatsCard>
```

Blazor Wasm complains about me mixing c# and markup with this error:

> Index.razor(12, 26): [RZ9986] Component attributes do not support
> complex content (mixed C# and markup). Attribute: 'Value', text:
> '_incomeExpensesSummaryData.PeriodIncome.ToString();,'

I know I could use member vars and assign form there but it is a bit dirty for some of my use cases.

Is there any trick I could use to accomplish this?

Comment: it looks pretty weird that there are no double quotes around the value?

Comment: Replacing `Value=@_incomeExpensesSummaryData.PeriodExpenses.ToString("0.00\u20AC")` with `Value="@(_incomeExpensesSummaryData.PeriodExpenses.ToString("0.00\u20AC"))"` should work.

Comment: Damn! I forgot the double quotes again. Yep this worked. If you create a response from your comment I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Xaver Apologies I've already added one.  We were answering this in parallel!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding double quotes around your attribute value.

```
<StatsCard Value="@_incomeExpensesSummaryData.PeriodExpenses.ToString("0.00\u20AC")" Description="Expenses" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Layers" IconColor="Color.Secondary"></StatsCard>
```

I tested this on the out-of-the-box index page

```
<SurveyPrompt Title="@dec.ToString("0.00\u20AC")" />
@code {

    private decimal dec = 5.34m;
}
```

[image]